# Как проверить и поменять значения в подмассивах?

Tags: python

```
t = [['234', 'True'], ['2353', 'False']]
y = [['234', 'False'], ['2353', 'False']]
```

Надо чтоб получилось в переменной y так:

```
y = [['234', 'True'], ['2353', 'False']]
```

т.е. значения True False из t применились к True False из y.
Пробовал цикл в цикле, но меняет каждый раз все заново.

Comment: *>значения True False из t применились к True False из y* - чего??

Comment: Пока что я как решение вижу `y = t`. :)

Comment: В буквальном смысле как написал, значения True False из первой переменной нужно проверить с такими же у второй и если они не совпадают, то поменять те которые у второй теми которые в первой...

Comment: Зачем тогда что-то менять, если можно сразу брать "из первой"?? Комментарий GrAnd Вам подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну буквально если то так:

```
t = [['234', 'True'], ['2353', 'False'], ['123', 'False']]
y = [['234', 'False'], ['2353', 'False'], ['321', 'True']]

d = dict(t)
for i in y:
    k,v = i
    if k in d and d[k] != v:
        i[1] = d[k]

print(y)
```

Вывод:

```
[['234', 'True'], ['2353', 'False'], ['321', 'True']]
```

Я добавил по несовпадающему элементу в списки, чтобы видно было, что меняется именно список `y`, а не просто мы присвоили в `y` ссылку на `t`.

Словарь сделан, чтобы быстрее искать элементы.

Ну а дальше буквально - идём по второму списку, смотрим есть ли такой элемент в первом списке, отличается ли он, и если есть, то подменяем этот элемент в списке во втором словаре.